# Having IE Troubles

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have recently built my own site www.poolspots.com.  I am new to css and I have been developing in FF.  When I checked it out in IE everything in the header and the footer is out of wack.  I was wondering if anybody has any idea on how to fix this problem.  If you look at it in FF it looks fine but when you look in IE it is way out of wack.  I did manage to get the border off of the logo but it is still there for the Social Network Icons.  Any help would be much appreciated.

P.S. I am not sure what version of IE I am using, I've looked everywhere but I can't find it.

Comment: Help -> About tells you the version.

Comment: @Cody And the UI, and JavaScript speeds are a big hint as well. (AFAIK, for anything post IE5.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your CSS `a img { border: 0 }`